# Microsoft Outlook Add-In not available on Android (but showing on IOS)

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have a published/certified MS Outlook Add-In on the Microsoft Store:
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381281?src=office&tab=Overview

It shows Product Supported: OfficeProductForAndroid and OfficeProductForIOS.  However, the Add-In only appears on IOS devices (as well as Desktop, OWA, etc).

How can I get support to know why the Add-in does not appear on Android devices?

PS - it does work by adding our XML staging manifest directly.  And other public store Add-Ins are working.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile(iOS and Android) add-in need to be whitelisted to show on Add-in Management Screen if it is not installed manually or not installed at all.
Whitelisting of Add-in is done by our team on request. I think franConnect has been whitelisted. Soon it will start coming on Addin Management Screen.

Comment: Just realized my addin (manually installed) isn't showing up on Android Outlook client , also Trello addin (Whitelisted by MS) isn't showing up.